# google-apps-script restric menu use/creation to users

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a sheet with a google apps script that does various things. One of those things is building a menu on open.

I would like this menu to be built only when a certain specific user is acessing the sheet. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have restrictions inside onOpen since the user's email address is not available in any context that allows a script to run without that user's authorization. You can however include checks in the function that runs on clicking menu items.

```
 function onOpen(e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
      .createMenu('Menu')
      .addItem('First item', 'doSomething')
      .addToUi();
}

 function doSomething() {
    if (Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() !== "abc@example.com") return;
    // else do something here
}
```